# Update SQL table to create order number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I recently updated SQL table to include order number to the rows. Now I have to write SQL statement to update rows with correct order values. It should look like this:

```
Id, UserName, Store, OrderNumber
1, User1, store1, 1
2, User2, store1, 2
3, User3, store1, 3
4, User4, store2, 1
5, User5, store2, 2
```

At the moment column OrderNumber contains only zero's.

How I should proceed?

Comment: you want to update orderNumber from which table? Please give more clarity in your question. what should be condition of your update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `ROW_NUMBER`

```
With CTE as
(
select row_number() Over(partition by Store order by Id) as O_number,*
From yourtable
)
Update CTE 
SET OrderNumber = O_number
```

Comment: Thanks. There is a small issue, but I fixed it. It should be:

select row_number() over (partition by Store order by Id) as O_number,*

Comment: @user6314 - yeah missed it. Updated